# correct syntax for php switch case statement when using arrays and adding elements to a different array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, switch-statement

Could you please help me find the correct syntax for putting a switch statement on an array, then on each case, add an element to a new array.

I have a 2-step form (which is actually 2 forms using the same php file).  On the first form, the user enters food names, chooses whether they want to use grams or cups as the serving size, and they choose a daily or weekly calculation.

Once the first form is submitted, matches to their foods are retrieved from the database and displayed in form #2 with a checkbox next to the food name. They can unselect any matches they don't want. This all works fine.

Upon submitting the second form, the amount of Vitamin C is calculated by pulling the amount of Vitamin C in each food from the database, in either grams or cups.  The php code calculates the amount of vitamin C based on what serving size they select (there are many options for grams and many options for cups).  This is the switch statement that I can't figure out.

Form #2 is:

```
<!--START DISPLAY OF FORM 2-->
                            <div class="step2">
                          <div class="row">
                                 <h2>Step 2 of 2</h2>
                                </div>
                              <div class="row"> <h3>We Found these matching foods. </h3> <ol><li><h4>Uncheck the ones you don't want to include in your calculation.</h4></li><li><h4>Enter your serving size.  If daily, enter amount of each food you feed your guinea pig each day.  If weekly, enter total amounts that you give him each week.</h4></li><li><h4>Click "Calculate my Vitamin C".</h4></li></ol></div>

                               <form id="step2" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">


                                   <?php  if ($servingsize == "grams") { 
                                      foreach ($results as $CurRes) {
                                    echo '<div class="row">' . '<div class="col-sm-1">' . '<input type="checkbox" name="foodname[]" ' . 'value="'.$CurRes['name'].'"' . 'checked>'. '</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-2">' .$CurRes['name'] .'</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-9">'; ?>
                                       <fieldset>
                                <!-- Select Basic -->
                                         <div class="control-group">
                                           <label class="control-label" for="amountg">Amount</label>
                                           <div class="controls">
                                             <select id="amountg" name="amountg[]" class="input-medium">
                                              <option value="10">10g</option>
                                              <option value="20">20g</option>
                                              <option value="30">30g</option>
                                              <option value="40">40g</option>
                                              <option value="50">50g</option>
                                              <option value="60">60g</option>
                                              <option value="70">70g</option>
                                              <option value="80">80g</option>
                                              <option value="90">90g</option>
                                              <option value="100">100g</option>
                                              <option value="110">110g</option>
                                              <option value="120">120g</option>
                                              <option value="130">130g</option>
                                              <option value="140">140g</option>
                                              <option value="150">150g</option>
                                              <option value="160">160g</option>
                                              <option value="170">170g</option>
                                              <option value="180">180g</option>
                                              <option value="190">190g</option>
                                              <option value="200">200g</option>
                                             </select>
                                               </fieldset>
                                              </div><!--end of div class controls-->
                                             </div><!--end of div class control-group-->
                                           </div><!--end of div class-col-sm-9-->
                                         </div><!--end of div class=row-->
                                 <?php } //end of foreach 
                            } else /*end of if servingsize="grams"*/ { 
                               foreach ($results as $CurRes) { 
                                     echo '<div class="row">' . '<div class="col-sm-1">' . '<input type="checkbox" name="foodnames[]" ' . 'value="'.$CurRes['name'].'"' . 'checked>'. '</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-2">' .$CurRes['name'] .'</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-9">'; ?>
                               <fieldset> 
                                <!-- Select Basic -->
                                  <div class="control-group" style="display:inline">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="cups">Amount</label>
                                    <div class="controls" style="display:inline">
                                     <select id="cups" name="cups" class="input-medium">
                                       <option value="1/4">1/4 cup</option>
                                       <option value="1/2">1/2 cup</option>
                                       <option value="3/4">3/4 cup</option>
                                       <option value="1">1 cup</option>
                                       <option value="1 1/4">1 1/4 cups</option>
                                       <option value="1 1/2">1 1/2 cups</option>
                                       <option value="1 3/4">1 3/4 cups</option>
                                       <option value="2">2 cups</option>
                                       <option value="2 1/4">2 1/4 cups</option>
                                       <option value="2 1/2">2 1/2 cups</option>
                                       <option value="2 3/4">2 3/4 cups</option>
                                       <option value="3">3 cups</option>
                                     </select>
                                     </div><!--end of div class controls-->
                                    </div><!--end of div class control-group-->
                                   </div><!--end of div class col-sm-5-->
                                 </div><!--end of div class row-->
                               </fieldset>
                             <?php } /*end of foreach*/
             } /* end of else - (is cups)*/ ?>
                         <p><input type="submit" value="Calculate my Vitamin C" name="form2"></p> 
                      </form>
           </div><!--end of <div class="step2">-->


 <!--END STEP 2-->
```

The switch statement is:

```
/*GOAL HERE IS: take the amount they selected on the form and convert the mysql results based on serving size.  For example, if they selected 50 grams, that's .5 * $curRes['mgc100g']*/
if (isset($_POST['form2'])) {
if ($servingsize == "grams") {
foreach ($_POST['foodname'] as $value) {
    $vitc=array();
    switch ($value) {
      case "10":
         $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/10;
         break;
      case "20":
         $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/5;
         break;
      case "30":
          $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/3.3333;
         break;
      case "40":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/2.5;
         break;
      case "50":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/2;
         break;
      case "60":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/1.667;
        break;
      case "70":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/1.4286;
        break;
      case "80":
             $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/1.25;
        break;
      case "90":
             $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']/1.1111;
        break;
      case "100":
             $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g'];
        break;
      case "110":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.1;
        break;
      case "120":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.2;
        break;
      case "130":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.3;
        break;
      case "140":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.4;
        break;
      case "150":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.5;
        break;
      case "160":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.6;
        break;
      case "170":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.7;
        break;
      case "180":
           $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.8;
        break;
      case "190":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*1.9;
        break;
     case "200":
            $vitc[] = $curRes['mgc100g']*2;
        break;
     default:
        echo "We couldn't calculate that. Sorry!";
     }//end of switch statement
     return $vitc;
    } //end of foreach loop
   } else { //end of if $servingsize == grams
foreach ($_POST['foodnames'] as $values) {
  $vitcc = array();
    switch ($value) {
        case "1/4":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']/4;
        break;
        case "1/2":
           $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']/2;
        break;
        case "3/4":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']/1.3333;
        break;
        case "1":
           $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup'];
        break;
        case "1 1/4":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*1.25;
        break;
        case "1 1/2":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*1.5;
        break;
        case "1 3/4":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*1.75;
        break;
        case "2":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*2;
        break;
        case "2 1/4":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*2.25;
        break;
        case "2 1/2":
          $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*2.5;
        break;
        case "2 3/4":
           $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*2.75;
        break;
        case "3":
           $vitcc[] = $curRes['mgc1cup']*3;
        break;
     default:
        echo "We couldn't calculate that. Sorry!";
     }//end of switch statement
     return $vitcc;
    } //end of foreach loop
  } //end of else statement (i.e., $servingsize is cups)
 } //end of if isset($_POST('form2'))
/*ADD TOTAL OF VITAMIN C mg*/
if ($_POST['radios'] == "grams") {
   foreach ($vitc as $amount) {
    $totalvitcgrams = round(array_sum($vitc), 1);
     return $totalvitcgrams;
        } //end of foreach
} elseif ($_POST['radios'] == "cups") {  //end of if $_POST['amountg'] == grams
   foreach ($vitcc as $amounts) {
    $totalvitccups = round(array_sum($vitcc), 1);
     return $totalvitccups;
        } //end of foreach
} /* end of elseif ($_POST['amountg'] != grams*/ else {
    echo 'An error occurred.  Sorry!'; }
//Calculate daily amount of Vitamin c from weekly totals
if ($weekly == "true") {
  $weektodaygrams = $totalvitcgrams/7;
  $weektodaycups = $totalvitccups/7;
}//end of if $weekly == true
?>
```

I get "Error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 320)" which is  "return $totalvitccups;"

$curRes['mgc1cup'] is the data pulled from the database.

I've tried everything I can think of for two days and I still can't get it to work.

So I have an array from the form called foodname[].  I need to go through each submitted foodname, and if it's there, do a calculation on it based on selected serving size, and then stick the result into an array, which I've named vitc (for grams) and vitcc (for cups).

I've done a var_dump on everything and put it in several places in the code, but I nothing gets displayed.  The only error I get is the invalid argument, which isn't helping me much.

So how can I take each calculation in each case of the switch statement and add it onto an array? Because after I have the array, I will add all values in the array together to get the total amount.  Getting the array is the problem.

The entire code is long, but if you want to see, it is [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/axn3-qi4n). The field forms can go from 1-20 fields for the food names (dynamically populated with javascript).

If you need to see it with the javascript enabled, it's [here](http://abyssinianguineapigtips.com/vitamin-c-calculator/) (enter 'hello').

My coding is not great.  I read 3 books on php and completed 2 online courses for php, but yet when I sit down to code, I have major problems getting stuff to do what I want it to.  But I keep trying and trying and trying. But this time I'm really stuck.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['foodnames'] as $values)` <-- notice that you use `$values` here and `$value` in the switch on the next line

Comment: You are also emptying your $vitcc array on each loop iteration. And you should use a lookup table to just transform `2 3/4` strings into floats beforehand.

Comment: several problems with this, will post answer to clarify a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off,

```
$vitc = array();
&
$vitcc = array();
```

both need to be outside your foreach (above), else they will get recreated each iteration and only contain the last value.

Second, regarding the error you're getting,

```
return $totalvitcgrams;
&
return $totalvitccups;
```

both of these also need to be outside the foreach loops (below)

And keep in mind the variable names you use, as @Sumurai8 said in the comments, you're using the wrong variable name `$values` vs `$value`

Also, you need to remove

```
return $vitc;
&
return $vitcc;
```

from the end of your switch.

You could also, very simply, simplify this by doing something like:

```
$vitc = array();
foreach($_POST['foodnames'] as $value){
    $vitc[] = $curRes['mcg100g'] / (100 / $value);
}
```

no need for a switch statement like this.

Or in your `<option>` tag just supply the correct value. The value doesn't have to match the text of the option. That would also alleviate the need for such a cumbersome switch and leave you with a simply foreach loop

Comment: Thank you.  The foreach loop is definitely a much better way of doing it.